# Is it okay to create a subclass of WritableRaster instead of using Raster.createWritableRaster?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d, raster

The JavaDoc of `java.awt.WritableRaster` says:

> The constructors of this class are protected.  To instantiate a `WritableRaster`, use one of the `createWritableRaster` factory methods in the `Raster` class.

I'm using custom a `DataBuffer` subclass (NIO `ByteBuffer` backed) of type `DataBuffer.TYPE_INT`, so I can't use the factory method [1]. I could use the class `sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster` directly like the factory method does, but I don't like to have a dependency on sun.* classes. So instead, I created a subclass of `WritableRaster` like this:

```
class GenericWritableRaster extends WritableRaster {
    public GenericWritableRaster(final SampleModel model, final DataBuffer buffer, final Point origin) {
        super(model, buffer, origin);
    }
}
```

(It also has a `toString()` method, but that's really it).

It seems to work fine for my needs so far, but **what are the possible compatibility or performance implications doing this?**

[1] Because of a possible JDK bug, the `createWritableRaster(SampleModel, DataBuffer, Point)` method assumes that any `DataBuffer` with type `DataBuffer.TYPE_INT` is actually a `java.awt.DataBufferInt` leading to an exception in `IntegerInterleavedRaster` constructor later.